# mongoose.findOne returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to retrieve todo by id. Code for getTodo service method is as below:

```
const getTodo = async (id, userId) => {
  const todo = await Todo.findOne({ id: id, userId: userId });
  return todo;
};
```

code from router which acts as a controller is as below:

```
router.get("/:id", tokenValidation.validate, async (req, res) => {
  const serverResponse = { ...defaultResponse };
  try {
    const decodedToken = jwt.decode(
      req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1].trim()
    );
    const getTodo = await todoService.getTodo(req.params.id, decodedToken.id);
    serverResponse.status = 200;
    serverResponse.body = getTodo;
    serverResponse.message = "Get todo by id";
  } catch (error) {
    serverResponse.message = error.message;
  }

  return res.status(serverResponse.status).send(serverResponse);
});
```

But the result is always null, on calling:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/todos/60422718e9db822de8531e87

{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Get todo by id",
    "body": null
}
```

What is missing in findOne method. Todo with id exists in the collection but is not returned. Please let me know what is missing.

Thanks

Comment: Is `decodedToken.id` value existed in Todo document with id is `60422718e9db822de8531e87`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use with `AND` operator

```js
const getTodo = async(id, userId) => {
  const todo = await Todo.findOne({
    $and: [{
        _id: id
      },
      {
        userId: userId
      }
    ]
  });
  return todo;
};
```

So this will return results with the combined conditions.

Comment: The above solution worked. Should be using _id instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

```
const getTodo = async (id, userId) => {
  const todo = await Todo.findOne({ id: id, userId: userId });
  return todo;
};
```

mongoose does not have "id" property. it has `_id` so you should query:

```
const todo = await Todo.findOne({ _id: id, userId: userId })
```

you dont need to pass two arguments. they both reflect same. "id" is already unique. you could just query:

```
    const todo = await Todo.findById(id)
```

Comment: But it belongs to a particular user.

Comment: @PrathameshMore try  { _id: id, userId: userId } if you want this way